# VBA Loop through the amount of rows given in InputBox

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I would like to loop through the amount of rows that are entered in the Input box +1.

```
Sub LoopEnter()
    myNum = Application.InputBox("Enter number")
    For Each r In Range ("A2":"A" & myNum +1)
        r.Offset (0.1) = "N"& r
        Next r
    End Sub
```

However, `("A2":"A" & myNum +1)` is not recognized as a range. What's the correct way to make the range, for example (A2:A41) if the number entered in the InputBox is 40?

Comment: Use `"N" & r.Row` to get row number

Comment: Well spotted. I updated my answer to reflect your insight :0)

Comment: You could also use `Range ("A2").resize(myNum)` and avoid concatenating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this ...

```
Sub LoopEnter()
    myNum = Application.InputBox("Enter number")
    For Each r In Range ("A2:A" & myNum +1)
        r.Offset (0,1) = "N" & r.Row
    Next r
End Sub
```

You had the `:` in the wrong place ... it should be inside the string, not between two strings!

---

Updated as suggested by @Santosh, as you'd also missed `.Row` out ... `r` is a `Range` object, `r.Row` is the row number property of that `Range` object.